# MySQL timezone confusion

Tags: php, mysql

I am completely stumped on what the heck is going on with an insert.  Basically, I'm trying to do the right thing by storing everything in the database in UTC and then converting to local timezone based on the user's information.  I have numerous queries that are working just fine, but this one insert query is throwing a wrench into the works.

```
$adt = date('Y-m-d') . " " . $_POST['Time'];
echo $adt;
$tmp_dt = new DateTime($adt, new DateTimeZone($tz));
echo $tmp_dt->format('H:i:s');  
$tmp_dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$UTC_time = $tmp_dt->format('H:i:s');
echo $UTC_time;

echo 'date_default_timezone_set: ' . date_default_timezone_get() . '<br />';
mysql_select_db($db_name, $JewelryDB);
mysql_query("SET time_zone = '+00:00';");

$updateSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO reminder_cfg 
                    (id, day_of, day_of_advance, day_prior, default_time, week_prior, 2_week_prior, 3_week_prior, 4_week_prior, 5_week_prior, day_after, 2_week_after, 50_day_after) 
                    VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
                    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE day_of = %s, day_of_advance = %s, day_prior = %s, default_time = %s, week_prior = %s, 2_week_prior = %s, 3_week_prior = %s, 4_week_prior = %s, 5_week_prior = %s, day_after = %s, 2_week_after = %s, 50_day_after = %s",
                   GetSQLValueString($jeweler, "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['DayOf'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Advance'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['DayPrior'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($UTC_time, "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['WeekPrior'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['2WeeksPrior'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['3WeeksPrior'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['4WeeksPrior'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['5WeeksPrior'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['DayAfter'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['2WeeksAfter'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['50DaysAfter'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['DayOf'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Advance'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['DayPrior'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['Time'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['WeekPrior'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['2WeeksPrior'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['3WeeksPrior'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['4WeeksPrior'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['5WeeksPrior'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['DayAfter'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['2WeeksAfter'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['50DaysAfter'], "text"));

$Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $JewelryDB) or die("Insert query error: " . mysql_error());
```

The echo statements in the code show that my timezone conversion is working as expected, but the insert statement is somehow subtracting 5 hours to insert the time in the local timezone.  This is a shared/hosted server so I can't simply set the system time to UTC.  I thought that the MySQL "SET time_zone" would correct this.

Please help.  This is driving me nuts.

Comment: Better to store in timestamp.

Comment: As an aside to your question, PHP functions that start with mysql_ have been deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0. If you are in a position to do so, please consider updating your code to use the MySQLi or PDO extensions instead.

Comment: You can use `CONVERT_TZ`.

Comment: @SureshKamrushi: storing as Unix timestamps exchanges one set of problems for another. You lose all the flexibility and datatype enforcement rules of  the DATETIME SQL datatype and associated functions; you're limited to the Unix era; you still have to ensure that you're storing a UTC value rather than a local value.

Comment: First off...  Thanks for the warning about the MYSQLi, and I am hoping to get to converting everything in the near future.  Right now I'm trying to resolve a few major bugs before I look into that.

Comment: Now...  Storing as a datetime makes no sense in this context.  The value in question is the time when they want to receive system notifications.  A date in this context is absolutely meaningless and would only serve to be confusing in maintaining this going forward.  The real question is how do I keep MySQL from seeming to timezone adjust this time?

Comment: Why in the world would you store all this "2weeksafter", "50daysafter", "2weeksprior" etc. This is exactly why DateTime functions (be it in [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php) or [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)) were invented. If you want to query for a specific record "50 days after" you simply use `Date_Sub()`/`Date_Add()` for example. This has a huge "code smell".

Comment: With _timezone_ there is sooner or later _confusion_.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql makes a distinction between the `timestamp` data type and the confusingly similar `datetime` data type.  The `datetime` type has an implicit time zone (defined by you according to the weather outside your window), while the values stored in the `timestamp` type are implicitly converted to unixtime (UTC).  If you want your time zone conversions to stick, you should store your values as `datetime` rather than `timestamp`.